# How to run a test file taking into account the functions

Tags: r, testthat, golem

I create a golem project. I created a test file with the command *golem::add_fct("calc", with_test = T)*.
When i execute the command test_file, it doesn't find my function.

**test/testthat/test-calc.R**

```
test_that("multiplication works", {
  res <- calc(2, 2)
  expect_equal(res, 4)
})
```

**R/fct_functions.R**

```
calc <- function(a,b){ return(a*b) }
```

In console

```
> test_file("tests/testthat/test-calc.R")
[ FAIL 1 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 0 ]

── Error (test-calc.R:11:3): multiplication works ─────
Error in `calc()`: could not find function "calc"
```

Comment: is `calc` exported in the package `NAMESPACE`?

Comment: Hello @r2evans, function calc is not in NAMESPACE. how can I add it? I couldn't find the command in the *02_dev.R* file that allowed me to do this.

Comment: frankly I'm not familiar with `golem`, but I believe the under-pinning of it all is still an R package, and I recommend `roxygen2` documentation methods for that. See https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/ and https://r-pkgs.org/man.html for info. (Namely, look for the `#' @export` tag, it's what will be needed followed by rendering all `./man/` files with `devtools::document`.)

Comment: Hello @r2evans, thank for your help, I will see that.